cannot find -lssl even i give the path of libssl.so.1.1 in cross compilation
I am cross compiling my project which has dependency of paho_c which has dependecy of openssl.
The toolchain has libssl.so.1.1 and libcrypto.so.1.1
When i make the project it shows
bin/ld cannot find -lssl
instead of libssl.so.1.1 when i give libssl.so it works fine, but it to run on take libssl.so.1.1
this is the cmake for paho_c
${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY} is the path of libssl.so.1.1, I have given but still not ryour text
ExternalProject_Add(
  libpaho
  PREFIX ${PAHO_BIN}
  SOURCE_DIR ${PAHO_DIR}
  URL https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/archive/v${PAHO_LIBRARY_VERSION}.tar.gz
  CMAKE_ARGS 
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR> 
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib 
          -DPAHO_HIGH_PERFORMANCE=TRUE 
          -DPAHO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE 
          -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=${PAHO_C_TLS} 
          -DPAHO_HIGH_PERFORMANCE=TRUE 
          -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=${OPENSSL_BIN}
          -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}
          -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
          -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY}
          -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}
)
add_library(paho STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(paho libpaho)
set_target_properties(paho PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PAHO_STATIC_LIB})
set_target_properties(paho PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${PAHO_INCLUDES})

link_directories(${OPENSSL_BIN})


Do not describe the error. Instead, add it to the question post as is, copying its exact content. If you wonder why it is important, then see that question on meta

libssl.so.1.1 is not libssl.so.  Your linker is looking for libssl.so.  Does it exist?  Likely as a softlink to libssl.so.1.1?

I have two machines: one for cross-compiling and one where the executable will run. On both, only libssl.so.1.1 exists, but no libssl.so. In the cross-compilation process, I create a symlink in CMake:
cmake
Copy code
execute_process(
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink
${OPENSSL_BIN}/libssl.so.1.1 ${OPENSSL_BIN}/libssl.so
)
The build works fine. However, on the target machine, I need to create the symlink again to run the program. I want to avoid manually symlinking on the target and instead make the executable use libssl.so.1.1 directly in CMake. Is this possible?
